# What is the correct "Reject" action for suggested edits that are "incorrect"

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review

Many times I've encountered suggested edits that actually make the originally post worse, for example changing the correct spelling of a word to some incorrect spelling or perhaps less drastic incorrectly modifying the tags.

Sometimes the suggested edit generally improves the post and there is only a small *mistake* in which case I would click improve and either uncheck or leave checked the *suggested edit was helpful button*.

What I'm referring to is the cases where I would like to reject the review, and I was wondering which of the existing options is most appropriate, or should there be a new Option?

- *Invalid Edit* To me says that the user tried to use the *suggested edit* feature for something which it isn't meant for, i.e asking  another question or commenting. In this case they are using the feature correctly, its just an incorrect (as opposed to invalid) edit.
- The *vandalism* option doesn't seem to be the right choice since it
  connotes that the intentions of the edit were bad
- The *Minor Edit* also doesn't seem right, since it doesn't really
  indicate whats wrong (and of course it can be a major edit, just not
  a correct one
- The *Custom* option of course works, but gets a bit tedious... Not to
  mention that since the edit might seem correct to those that barely
  look at the suggested reviews before hitting approve its likely to get
  approved before you finish typing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you exclude *too minor* because there isn't anything else that needs to be edited, *vandalism* because the user's intention was to improve the post (which means that who suggested the edit didn't replace the post's text with "This is a really bad answer, and I would not be proud to show it."), and you don't want to use a custom reason, then you can choose *invalid edit*, which is a catch-all reason for those cases where the suggested edit is wrong/incorrect in some way, for example because it replaces *I* with *i* in a sentence like "I would use a different approach."

Answer (score 13):

Why not **Invalid Edit**?

> This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post

Comment: Because to me that implies that the use was trying to do something else, like edit in an answer inside a question, ask their own question or comment.

Comment: The first clause of that description says "This edit is incorrect"

Comment: Perhaps it's just me, but to me there seems to be a difference between invalid and incorrect.

Comment: I'll give you that the Invalid part seems a little odd, but given the description, it's the perfect choice for your situation.

Comment: OK, I'll wait and see if I get any other feedback and if not I'll go with that.

Comment: I would use--and have used--Invalid Edit.

Comment: @Jack This reason applies to both edits that make the post worse, as well as to actions that aren't proper types of edits (such as adding a comment as an edit).  Notice the "or" in the reason.  It applies to both situations.